# code kernel: ACPI Error: Could not disable RealTimeClock events (20230628/evxfevnt-243)

Tags: linux-kernel

```
 code kernel: i8042: PNP: No PS/2 controller found.
 code kernel: mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
 code kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver appletouch
 code kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver bcm5974
 code kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver synaptics_usb
 code kernel: rtc_cmos 00:04: RTC can wake from S4
 code kernel: ACPI Error: Could not disable RealTimeClock events (20230628/evxfevnt-243)
 code kernel: fbcon: Taking over console
 code kernel: rtc_cmos 00:04: registered as rtc0
 code kernel: rtc_cmos 00:04: setting system clock to 2024-02-14T10:36:34 UTC (1707906994)
 code kernel: ACPI Error: Could not disable RealTimeClock events (20230628/evxfevnt-243)
 code kernel: rtc_cmos 00:04: alarms up to one month, y3k, 242 bytes nvram
 code kernel: i2c_dev: i2c /dev entries driver
 code kernel: i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.1: SPD Write Disable is set
 code kernel: i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.1: SMBus using PCI interrupt
```

I found the ACPI Error after update kernel 6.7.
Please help

Comment: that sounds relatively benign, unless you do have problems with such events. Can you explain how this manifests as a problem?